# Powershell ExecWB()

Tags: powershell, scripting

I'm having a problem while printing a webpage through powershell.  I'm reading a file that contains part numbers, and then getting more information about that part through a website, and then prints the information to the users default printer.  Everything works fine except the website always has a blank page at then end of it.  Most of the parts are only two pages long but it always prints 3 and just says "Page 3 of 3" on the upper right hand side of the blank page with the web title on the upper left and the web address at the bottom.  Is there anyway using ExecWB(6,2) to print a page range?  Or do I need different parameters?
Here is the code:

```
$UNC = "\\\\FAPCOSRV\proscan\conv\conveyance.txt"
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($UNC)

try {
    $ie = New-Object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application 
    $ie.visible = $true 
    # $ie.silent = $true 
    for(;;) {
        $line = $reader.ReadLine()
        if ($line -eq $null) { break }
        $url = "http://75.144.71.189/specdata/specdata.asp?requiredmcpartno=" + $line
        $ie.Navigate( $url )
        while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 4} 
        $ie.ExecWB(6,2)
}
while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 4} 
$ie.quit()
}
finally {
    while( $ie.busy){Start-Sleep 4} 
    $ie.quit()
    $reader.Close()
}
```